# Ruby variable inside shorthand array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to insert a variable `deploy[:deploy_to]` into my shorthand array below.

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
    %w[ #{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/cache 
        #{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/public/projects_icons ].each do |path|
            directory path do
                user deploy[:user]
                group deploy[:group]
                mode "0777"
            end
       end
end
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `deploy[deploy_to]` is not a variable.

Comment: `deploy[:deploy_to]` is just a value in a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%W` supports interpolation:

```
%W[ #{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/cache 
    #{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/public/projects_icons ].each do |path|
        directory path do
            user deploy[:user]
            group deploy[:group]
            mode "0777"
        end
   end
```